# Python await' outside function Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, python-requests, discord.py

This bot check the web site with request module every 5 second
If product is not solded out. Bot has to send message to discord channel.
If it is solded out. 5 second later check again

```
 import discord
import requests
import re
import time
time.sleep(60)

client = discord.Client()

url = "https://wunder.com.tr/sneaker/adidas-sneaker/yeezy-boost-700-v3-H67799?gclid=CjwKCAjwnIr1BRAWEiwA6GpwNSZ5WT1GuFdTO1nXkwYLl__RXY0PZ6Atez4_ZYB-DSNEbzz3Z3swGRoCkAsQAvD_BwE"
a=1
b=2



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("----------------------")
    print("Logged In As")
    print("Username: %s"%client.user.name)
    print("ID: %s"%client.user.id)
    print("----------------------")


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    id = client.get_guild(703666065040867391)

while a<b:
    time.sleep(5)
    req = requests.get(url)
    if re.search('(?i)SOLD OUT',req.text):
        print('Nike Fear of God Checked'+ i)

    else:
        await message.channel.send('Stokta Var')
        print('Nike Fear of God Checked')





client.run('token')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using tasks in Discord.py
See [this](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks#discord.ext.tasks.loop) link.

But you must do `from discord.ext import tasks` in the begining of your code. Tasks are very helpful.

The reason you should use tasks is you cannot use await outside of an async function. Also, your code has a while True loop **before client.run**. That means, client.run will probably not execute.

Hope this helps

Comment: I am getting await error SyntaxError: 'await' outside function

Comment: You made an answer, but did not explain anything. Please consider editing your answer to make it better.